# How to construct URI with query arguments from hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, uri, ruby-2.2

How to construct URI object with query arguments by passing hash?

I can generate query with:

`URI::HTTPS.build(host: 'example.com', query: "a=#{hash[:a]}, b=#{[hash:b]}")`

which generates

`https://example.com?a=argument1&b=argument2`

however I think constructing query string for many arguments would be unreadable and hard to maintain. I would like to construct query string by passing hash. Like in example below:

```
hash = {
  a: 'argument1',
  b: 'argument2'
  #... dozen more arguments
}
URI::HTTPS.build(host: 'example.com', query: hash)
```

which raises

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_str' for {:a=>"argument1", :b=>"argument2"}:Hash
```

Is it possible to construct query string based on hash using URI api? I don't want to monkey patch hash object...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have ActiveSupport, just call [`'#to_query'`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_support_core_extensions.html#to_query) on hash.

```
hash = {
  a: 'argument1',
  b: 'argument2'
  #... dozen more arguments
}
URI::HTTPS.build(host: 'example.com', query: hash.to_query)
```

`=> https://example.com?a=argument1&b=argument2`

If you are not using rails remember to `require 'uri'`

Comment: `to_query` is a Rails only method. It does not exist in Ruby.

Comment: @marc_ferna questions has ruby on rails tag. You can include : ActiveSupport in non-rails projects

Answer (score 25):

For those not using Rails or Active Support, the solution using the Ruby standard library is

```
hash = {
  a: 'argument1',
  b: 'argument2'
}
URI::HTTPS.build(host: 'example.com', query: URI.encode_www_form(hash))
=> #<URI::HTTPS https://example.com?a=argument1&b=argument2>
```